# Save iteration results to list as a while loop is running in R

Tags: r, list, while-loop

Much has been discussed on SO regarding saving iteration results to list or data frames in R for repeat loops, but when I attempt to try these on my while loop, R does not update the list as the while loop is running. On top of that, once the while loop breaks, an empty list is returned.

My while loop is of the form

```
iter.res <- list()

repl <- function() {
    iters <- 1
    sim(N = n)
    while (x < y) {
        sim(N = ceiling(nn)) # a user-defined function
        iter.res[[iters]] <- nn
        iters <- iters + 1
    }
}
```

I am uncertain as to why 'iteration.res' is not being filled with values after each iteration is run.

Does someone know what this issue could be here and how to best go about addressing it?

Comment: Your function doesn't really return *anything*. I would recommend (a) don't use `assign`, (b) don't try to assign to something in the global environment, instead assign (with `<-` or `=`) to a list in the function environment, (c) `return()` the list after the while loop.

Comment: If you'll point me to any of the discussions on SO you reference where people are recommending using `assign(..., envir = .GlobalEnv)`, I'll go downvote them. I'm sure the top recommendations are along the lines of my comment above. Here, you can initalize `iters = 1` inside the function but before the loop. In the loop (presumably *after* assigning `iter.res[[iters]] <- nn` you can then do `iters = iters + 1`. The way you have things now, `iters` starts at 1 and the first thing you do is change it to `2`, so nothing happens while it is 1.

Comment: If you want more help, post a working example. `x` and `y` should be passed in to your function or defined in your function, and at least one of them needs to be updated in your function for the `while` loop to ever end.

Comment: In fact, this function is most `buggy` code I have seen ever. Not even a single line of this function looks correct. You can fix the code and then try to `return` list at the end.

Comment: Functions don't modify any objects outside of their scope (unless explicitly told to do so). Also, why don't you just calculate many simulations and subset those that satisfy `x < y`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The reason for not doing as you suggest is because all ofmy iterations satisfy x < y except the last one.

Comment: @Gregor I've made your suggested edits.

Comment: Your function should take every variable as input or have it defined inside the function. Currently, `n`, `x`, `y`, and `nn` have no visible definitions - they seem to come out of thin air. As stated before, you also don't ever seem to change `x` or `y`, which is needed for you `while` loop to break. To get help, post enough code for us to run an example. To test this, start a new R session, paste your code into it, and try to run it. When you've added enough for that to work, paste all the necessary definitions into your question.

Comment: For now I'm voting to close for the close reason *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question** itself"*

Comment: @Gregor Alright. Once I have a small reproducible example, I will repost. Regarding the use of assign(..) in R, what if the input to assign() is a model object (e.g. lm, glm, or nls)? To make these objects available in the global environment, I see no other alternative other than to use assign() (the use of <<- is outright dangerous).

Comment: Write models to a list and output that as the function result.

Comment: `assign` to the global environment and `<<-` are basically equivalent. It's ridiculous to claim one is good and one is "outright dangerous". As Roman says, you should `return()` everything that is needed outside the function. If you need multiple objects, you put them in a list and return the list.

Comment: @Gregor Sorry for the late response... I have decided just to write the iterations to a file using write(..., append = TRUE)